# r package for graphs with nested subgraphs?

Tags: r, graph, social-networking

I am looking for an r package for graphs / networks which can deal with nested subgraphs. Graphviz does this but only provides for visualisation - I want classes or some way of representing the data structures themselves. igraph has subgraphs but they can't be nested as far as I can see.

[image]

To clarify, I already use DiagrammeR and Rgraphviz for *drawing* networks - but I want to *analyse* and *manipulate* e.g., say,

(pseudocode)

```
newnet = oldnet + myAddedNode
```

to add a node to oldnet in order to make a new network called newnet.

Comment: doesn't `subgraph` do what you want?

Comment: Not sure, but have you looked at gephi?

Comment: @dudu, if you mean subgraph in Graphviz, yes, and indeed you can nest subgraphs. I am looking for a tool to *manipulate* graphs/networks (including ones with nested subgraphs)  which can then be, for example, visualised with graphviz. Rgraphviz isn't IMO a graph manipulation package.