# Setting subgraph/cluster attributes in Rgraphviz

Tags: r, graph, graphviz, r-graphviz

I want to plot a graph via Rgraphviz but I can't handle the design attributes of the clusters that I set.

There are similar questions already on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176209/setting-subgraph-attributes-in-rgraphviz) and [elsewhere](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/87593/) but none has a real minimal working example and none of them is answered. So I want to try to ask a complete question to receive a complete answer. As an introduction to the package, I read the [paper](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.7/bioc/vignettes/Rgraphviz/inst/doc/Rgraphviz.pdf) "How To Plot A Graph Using Rgraphviz" by Gentry, Gentleman, and Huber.

My example network:

```
library(Rgraphviz)

set.seed(123)
V <- letters[1:6]
M <- 1:4
g1 <- randomGraph(V, M, 0.2)
```

If I want to plot it, I can easily give it some attributes via a list:

```
attributes <- list(node = list(shape = "rectangle", fixedsize = FALSE), 
              graph = list(layout = "dot", bgcolor = "transparent"))

plot(g1, attrs = attributes )
```

Plotting it via `plot(g1)` gives the following result: [image]

Now I want to define two clusters/subgraphs. This can be done this way:

```
sg1= subGraph(c("a", "e", "f"), g1)
sg2= subGraph(c("b", "c", "d"), g1)
subGList <- vector(mode = "list", length = 2)
subGList[[1]] <- list(graph = sg1, cluster = TRUE)
subGList[[2]] <- list(graph = sg2, cluster = TRUE)
```

Plotting the graph again now including a `subGlist` argument:

```
plot(g1, attrs = attributes , subGList = subGList)
```

[image]

So, obviously, there has been a change in the setting and even though it would be convenient having the clusters a little bit more separated, the result is ok.

Now if I want to define cluster-specific styles or try to have them framed, I start having problems. According to page 4 of the mentioned introductory paper one can simply add an element called `attrs` to the sublists of `subGlist`.

To my understanding, it *should* work this way:

```
subGList[[1]] <- list(graph = sg1,
                      cluster = TRUE,
                      attrs = c(fontcolor = "red"))

plot(g1, attrs = attrs, subGList = subGList)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't. As mentioned, I would like to frame my clusters (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736324/r-package-for-graphs-with-nested-subgraphs) SO post) but as I can't even handle the fontcolors of the clusters, I think I make a somehow more fundamental mistake.

My complete code:

```
library(Rgraphviz)

set.seed(123)
V <- letters[1:6]
M <- 1:4
g1 <- randomGraph(V, M, 0.2)

attributes <- list(node = list(shape = "rectangle", fixedsize = FALSE), 
                   graph = list(layout = "dot", bgcolor = "transparent"))

#plot(g1, attrs = attributes )

sg1= subGraph(c("a", "e", "f"), g1)
sg2= subGraph(c("b", "c", "d"), g1)
subGList <- vector(mode = "list", length = 2)
subGList[[1]] <- list(graph = sg1, cluster = TRUE)
subGList[[2]] <- list(graph = sg2, cluster = TRUE)

#plot(g1, attrs = attributes , subGList = subGList)

subGList[[1]] <- list(graph = sg1,
                      cluster = TRUE,
                      attrs = c(fontcolor = "red"))

plot(g1, attrs = attrs, subGList = subGList)
```

I hope someone can help! Thank you